# sql query dependant column

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have two tables

one is keywords [id | keyword | account] k
and one is templateKeywordLink [templateId | keywordId] tkl

What I want to do is get a result set with all keywords from the keywords table (where account = 1)

I also want to add another column called selected.

if `k.id in (select templateId from templateKeywordLink)` then selected should contain "selected". else it should be null

Im wondering what the optimal query is to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.  One way is to do a left join against a query that returns the IDs of interest.

Note that most databases have more compact ways to do what I did with a CASE statement, but CASE is portable to any relational database you could want to use.

```
SELECT k.*
  , CASE
      WHEN tkl.id IS NULL
      THEN NULL
      ELSE 'selected'
    END as selected
FROM keywords k
  LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT DISTINCT templateId
      FROM templateKeywordLink
    ) as tkl
    ON k.id = tkl.templateId
```